# pass variable between methods in WCF service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

How pass variable between methods in WCF service? I tried to use fields, properties, session but all of them as client call different method it get reset.For example I need to send Authentication from 1st method to rest of the methods.

Comment: can you step into the code..? I appears that you may need to have a a property for private bool Auth if not you will need a Static variable to retain the bool state of Auth button Clicks do full postback and loading of pages as well as resetting public and private variables to their default value..

Comment: I used property for Auth as wll like:   public bool Auth { get; set; } but still that is not keeping value too.

Comment: what if you return something like `this.Auth` if worse comes to worse assign it to a Session Variable using `HttpContext.Current.Session["Auth"] = false`

Comment: @ DJ KRAZE I try to keep in the session but still when I call second method the Auth back to false

Comment: have you stepped thru the code..? it's hard to determine what you are or are not doing without knowing all debugging details

Answer (score 0):

You need to use per-session instance creation, which will keep a dedicated service class instance for the session. Per-session instancing should be avoided where possible because it does not scale well.

Set `InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession` on the service as a behaviour and `SessionMode=SessionMode.Required` on the service contract. This will make your service fail if you accidentally attempt to use a binding that doesn't support sessions - WsHttpBinding or NetTcpBinding are OK, but not BasicHttpBinding.

See [WCF Instance Management - PerSession Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664815/wcf-instance-management-persession-mode) and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Code from the article cited from that question showing the use of the attributes (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per#Per%20session%20Instance%20mode):

```
namespace Northwind.ServiceContracts
{
    [ServiceContract(Name = "CustomerCartService",
        Namespace = "http://northwind.com/CustomerCartService",
        SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
    public interface ICustomerCartService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool AddProductsToCart(int productID);
    }
}

namespace Northwind.CustomerCartServices
{
    [ServiceBehavior(Name = "CategoryService",
         Namespace = "http://northwind.com/CustomerCartService",
         InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession )] 
    public class CustomerCartService : ICustomerCartService
    {
        public bool AddProductsToCart(int productID);
        {
            // code for adding product to customer cart.
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```